# Cant understand full_join error: atributes of different sizes

Tags: r, dplyr

Encountering an error I've never seen before and a rather extensive google/SO/mailing list search has come up empty.

When using `full_join` in a for loop I'm getting the following error after 75% of the for loop iterations have iterated:

`Error in full_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) : 
      atributes of different sizes`

What does this error mean? I've been trying to understand what it is referring to. The best I could come up with was to test the lengths of the attributes of my two tbl_dfs and found that `length(attributes(x))` is the same as `length(attributes(y))`

I've run `traceback()` which results in the following when I get my error:

```

```
5: stop(list(message = "atributes of different sizes", call = full_join_impl(x, 
       y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y), cppstack = list(file = "", 
       line = -1L, stack = "C++ stack not available on this system")))
4: .Call("dplyr_full_join_impl", PACKAGE = "dplyr", x, y, by_x, 
       by_y, suffix_x, suffix_y)
3: full_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y)
2: full_join.tbl_df(x, y, by = c("common col1", "common col2"))
1: full_join(x, y, by = c("common col1", "common col2")) at #50
```

```

Comment: I had this same error and sorted it by making sure the variable I was joining by had the same type in each data frame. However, when I tried to replicate the problem, it returned a much more informative error ("Error: Can't join on 'id' x 'id' because of incompatible types (factor / integer)"), rather than this one about the attributes.